# setting state on react native issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

Am trying to print out the data I get from a back end server built with nodejs on my react native app  screen using axios but for some reason I get no results

here is the code i used :

my useArticle hook code :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import articles from "../api/articles";
import axios from "axios";
export default () => {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState([]);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState("");
  const loadApi = async () => {
    // wait for a reponse to get back once it does with some data we asign that data to the reponse variable
    try {
      const response = await axios.get("http://localhost/articles");
      //console.log(response.data);
      setDocs(Array.from(response.data));
    } catch (err) {
      setErrorMessage("Something went wrong");
    }
  };
  // bad code
  //searchApi("pasta");
  useEffect(() => {
    loadApi();
  }, []);

  return [loadApi, docs, errorMessage];
};

// we extracted the resutls logic into this helper function we then imported
// to the main screen in order to use SearchApi , results , errorMessage
// now this helper function can be used inside other components
```

and here the screen that supposed to show the results :

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, ScrollView, FlatList } from "react-native";
import SearchBar from "../components/SearchBar";
import useResults from "../hooks/useResults";
import ResutlsList from "../components/ResultsList";
import ResutlsListVer from "../components/ResultsListVer";
import useArticles from "../hooks/useArticles";
const TrackCreateScreen = () => {
  const [loadApi, docs, errorMessage] = useArticles();

  /*****************************FUNCTION TO FILTER OUT RESULTS SHOWING USING THE PRICE *************************/

  /*******************************WE WONT NEED THIS UP NOT DOWN************************************* */
  /******************************** REMOVE VIEW AND REPLACE IT WITH <> SO WE DONT HAVE TO WORRY ABOUT ADDING FLEX **********************************************/
  return (
    <View>
      {docs.map((article, index) => (
        <Text key={index}>{article.title}</Text>
      ))}
      <Text style={styles.Text}>{docs.length}</Text>

      <FlatList
        data={docs}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={{ backgroundColor: "#abc123", padding: 10, margin: 10 }}>
            <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>
              {item.title}
            </Text>
            <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>{item.excerpt}</Text>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    //flex: 1, // when ever we have a content that is being cut off or expanding off the screen
  },
  Text: {
    fontSize: 32,
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});
export default TrackCreateScreen;
```

I did some console. logs and for some reason the docs in useState is just an empty array, even though when I used console.log (response. data) I got all the results shown on my console.

Am also trying to filter out the null values from my API and just show the ones with actual value so if anyone could point out to me how I will be able to do that it will be much appreciated.

here is a sample of data i get when i used console.log(response.data) :

```
Object {
  "data": Array [
    Object {
      "_id": "5eb95a068d162448a4e6a9c2",
      "excerpt": "The shooting of Ahmaud Arbery.",
      "img": null,
      "task_id": "92e563d3-82c0-4f13-b393-15d5e570dfad",
      "title": null,
    },
    Object {
      "_id": "5eb95a068d162448a4e6a9c3",
      "excerpt": null,
      "img": null,
      "task_id": "92e563d3-82c0-4f13-b393-15d5e570dfad",
      "title": null,
    },
    Object {
      "_id": "5eb95a068d162448a4e6a9c4",
      "excerpt": null,
      "img": null,
      "task_id": "92e563d3-82c0-4f13-b393-15d5e570dfad",
      "title": null,
    },
    Object {
      "_id": "5eb95a068d162448a4e6a9c5",
      "excerpt": null,
      "img": null,
      "task_id": "92e563d3-82c0-4f13-b393-15d5e570dfad",
      "title": null,
    },
```

Comment: try to save the return value of Array.from(response.data) in a variable first and then console that variable  to crosscheck that if you still get the data;

e.g

const newValue = Array.from(response.data);
console.log(newValue);

Comment: when i used this const newValue = Array.from(response.data); console.log(newValue); it returned an empty array too for some reason

Comment: double check the URL is correct, are you positive this is the right URL: `http://localhost/articles` ? put that in your browser and see if anything comes up

Comment: yes obviously the URL is correct or else the console.log(response.data) would not return any results

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be in the Array.from method since from console it can be seen you are already getting array so need to convert it  further

### Instead of this

```
setDocs(Array.from(response.data));
```

try

```
 setDocs(response.data.data);
```

Comment: i had this before i used Array.form and it gave me a Type error undefined is not a function on doc.map cause the response.docs is of type {} instead of []

Comment: test this out for me @Souhaildq  setDocs(response.data.data)

Comment: am sorry i meant responose.data is of type {} instead of []  there is no response.docs my bad and the error was caused by docs.map cause it requires objects of type [] not {} thats why i used Array.form @Towerss

Answer (score 0):

If you have used `setState` function, then there might be an issue with `setDoc()` as it takes time to set your data, since `setState` is an `async` function.

Comment: Okay, then try setDoc(Array.from(response.data.data),
as your response.data has one more object name as data.